# subir java web application a xampp

Tags: java, jsp, xampp, tomcat

He realizado mi primer java web en netbeans y ahora tengo que subirlo a un servidor local (xampp) el tema es que no entiendo bien el tema, generé el archivo `.war` (haciendo click derecho en el proyecto en netbeans y luego clean and build) luego tome el `.war` y lo lleve a `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps`, cree una carpeta `x` y metí el `.war` dentro 
`C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\x`, luego en el navegador pongo `localhost:8080/x/index.jsp` y me sale error:

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
>
> type Status report
>
> messageNot Found
>
> descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

He buscado, pero no me sale nada al respecto. Gracias.

Comment: Porqué no utilizas una instalación de Tomcat (excluyendo el xampp), hasta donde sé xampp es para cosas de PHP, un war (para caso de Tomcat) debe colocarse en la carpeta `webapps`, lo más sencillo es tener el `autodeploy` activo, de esa manera el war se desplegará en cuanto inicies el servicio de Tomcat, para ubicar el url correcto debes fijarte como has definido tu contexto en el web.xml de tu aplicación. Esto te puede servir http://programacion.net/articulo/desplegar_servlets_y_aplicaciones_web_en_tomcat_y_weblogic_server_175

Comment: @RosendoRopher he bajado tomcat y no se encuentra esa carpeta applications, lo otro se bajo un archivo.rar este lo descomprimi, no salia ningun ejecutable, es asi? solo carpetas?

Comment: Edité mi comentario, el directorio es `webapps`

Comment: @RosendoRopher ya he puesto mi .war en esa carpeta de tomcat bajado aparte, ahora solo necesito ese archivo? y como lo puedo visualizar en el navegador?
gracias

Comment: Tenemos algún avance @elsa?

Comment: @RosendoRopher no, cuando intento levantar tomcat con el archivo startup de win, se abre la cmd y se cierra de inmediato, no hace lo que mostrabas en la foto

Comment: El scritp `startup.*` lo que hace es llamar al script `catalina.*` prueba con ese a ver o si no directamente con el `tomcat.exe`, dudo que funcione pero intentalo. Puedes ver si existe en la carpeta `logs` algún fichero para la fecha de hoy y ver si tiene alguna pista?

Comment: Lo has logrado @elsa?

Comment: si, logre hacerlo pero con glassfish

Comment: Huuummm, está raro que no hayas podido con Tomcat, en teoría era mucho más fácil que con Glassfish :)

Comment: Xampp si que permite tener un servidor Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Hola tengo entendido que XAMPP ahora incorpora apache tomcat, ahora si quieres usar xampp a manera de aprendizaje, verifica que el servicio de tomcat este encendido, se ve un indicador de color verde. Si ves el servicio encendido intenta entrando a : localhost:8080

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque considero mejor utilizar solo tomcat, tal como lo menciona el compañero en el post de arriba.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea del mensaje de error:

> "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1"

Indica que no estás accediendo al Tomcat.

Puede que ni lo tengas arrancado, o si lo tienes arrancado sea en otro puerto.

> GlassFish es otro servidor alternativo a Tomcat.

Una posibilidad es que, al intentar arrancar el tomcat, como ya tenías arrancado GlassFish en el mismo puerto, el **Tomcat** fallara al arrancar.

¿Podría ser que uses GlassFish como servidor del netbeans para desarrollo y por eso está ejecutándose?

Answer (score 0):

Descarga Tomcat y descomprime el .zip en algún lugar de tu equipo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coloca tu war en la carpeta `webapps`

Dentro de la carpeta `bin` encontrarás los scripts (startup.*) para poder iniciar el servicio `.bat` si estas en Windows, `.sh` si estás en Linux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el directorio `conf` se encuentra el fichero `server.xml` en donde (por default) se encuentra la opcion `autodeploy` con valor `true` esto significa que cuando arranques tu servicio de Tomcat se desplegaran todos los wars que se encuentren en la carpeta `webapps`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes verificarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con todo lo anterior, al arrancar el servicio de Tomcat deberás ver algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tu aplicación (si no tiene algún problema) deberá ser accesible desde un navegador, ¿donde?

Puedes verificar en el mismo server.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Update**

Para tus problemas al arrancar el Tomcat te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. Verifica que existe (realmente) la variable de entorno JAVA_HOME
2. Mediante `cmd` ubícate en el directorio `/bin` de Tomcat ejecuta directamente el siguiente comando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no tienes la variable de entorno configurada, debes hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso tengo Java 7, luego de esto no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no se si te sirva mi respuesta pero al crear algunas paginas ya sea en C# por ejemplo.
Cuando tenia el como tal la pagina creata y compilada basicamente lo que hacia es copiar la app a la carpeta WWW y configurar el puerto en donde se iba a ejecutar.

El problema es que bueno como tal lo que yo hacia no era una app si no una pag web bastante basica, ya que para eso mejor lo monto en ISS que es bastante sencillo bueno cuando trabajo con C# y aplicaciones usando entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que querés es que alojar tu app en un localhost, en la parte de arriba del archivo jnlp la dirección de codebase, tené en cuenta que si usás xampp sólo colocas localhost y el nombre de la carpeta donde está alojado el archivo, osea, que si tu ubicación es: C:\xampp\htdocs\java-prueba   entonces colocás http://localhost/java-prueba  espero no equivocarme.

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que veo tu provecto lo generaste con el glassfish, para esto hay que entender que una aplicación web hecha en java siempre necesita un servidor, por obvias razones para desplegar la aplicación se necesita hacerlo sobre el mismo servidor que se desarrollo, en este caso lo que imagino es que instalaste netbeans y empezaste a trabajar sin tomar en cuenta una arquitectura, netbeans cuando lo instalas por default trae el servidor glassfish por eso cuando despliegas la aplicación te pide GlassFish 4.1.1.1 la forma correcta para desplegar tu proyecto es la siguiente:

1. Descargar el servidor glassfish de su página oficia.
2. Descomprimir el servidor en algún lugar de tu equipo.
3. Iniciar el servidor glassfish.
4. Acceder a localhost:4848 que es la consola de administración de glassfish
5. Si utilizaste motores de persistencia en tu aplicación generar el pool de conexión.
6. En la consola de administración navegar al menú de aplication, depues elegir la opción de deploy y elegir el war generado por netbeans.

Luego de esto podrás entrar a la dirección de tu aplicación: localhos:8080/Miaplicion

Espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Estimado, lo que mencionas no es correcto. Un `war` es un `war` en cualquier contenedor de aplicaciones. Puedes desarrollar usando el contenedor que tengas a mano y eso no significa que es el que deberás usar en tu entorno productivo.

Comment: a que te refieres que no tome en cuenta la arquitectura?